# Loading NetCDF file on QGIS as raster

Tags: qgis, raster, netcdf

I have gotten very rusty at QGIS.

I am attempting to load a NetCDF file of the average monthly temperature for a midwestern state. I go through the normal [layer-add layer- raster] steps and for some reason, it is showing up as an RGB map with no values in the attribute table, and it has way more bands than 12 (it should have only 1 for each month).

Where did I go wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 3 options to load a netCDF correctly in QGIS

1. go through layer > add layer > add meshlayer

[image]

2. use the datasource manager -> Mesh

[image]

3. just drag and drop it from the browser

[image]