# Reading multi-dimensional NetCDF files using QGIS

Tags: qgis, netcdf

I am trying to load NetCDF files in QGIS using `Layer > Add Layer > Add Raster Layer` but the software crashes. I wonder if QGIS can load multi-dimensional NetCDF files or not because I have tried importing *.NC files without the `Dimensions without coordinates` (when lon and lat are directly linked to the variables) and it works ok.

I also tried opening it with `Layer > Add Layer > Add Mesh Layer` but it gives incorrectly projected results with no options to select a specific variable. The projection doesn't update even when I changed it.

The *.NC file I want to view is read in Python as follows:

```
Dimensions:          (CELL: 862, FOUR: 4, NODE: 1214, KC: 10, LCM: 864,
                      NSXD: 1, TIME: 73, NALG: 3)
Coordinates:
    lonc             (CELL) float32 ...
    latc             (CELL) float32 ...
    sigma            (CELL, KC) float32 ...
    time             (TIME) object ...
Dimensions without coordinates: CELL, FOUR, NODE, KC, LCM, NSXD, TIME, NALG
Data variables: (12/33)
    mesh             uint32 ...
    nv               (CELL, FOUR) uint32 ...
    lon              (NODE) float32 ...
    lat              (NODE) float32 ...
    layers           (CELL) int8 ...
    bottom_layer     (CELL) int8 ...
              ...
    NHX              (TIME, KC, CELL) float32 ...
    NOX              (TIME, KC, CELL) float32 ...
    SAA              (TIME, KC, CELL) float32 ...
    COD              (TIME, KC, CELL) float32 ...
    DOX              (TIME, KC, CELL) float32 ...
    ALG              (TIME, NALG, KC, CELL) float32 ...
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.4
    Base_date:    1990-01-01 00:00:00
    Project:      EFDC
    utm_zone:     UTM Zone  17 Northern Hemisphere
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/463021/87346

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work with Add Mesh Layer either..